# Why isn't \prime automatically set to be a superscript?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In math mode, writing `\prime` gives too big a "prime" symbol, and it isn't a superscript, like it always is in textbooks. Why is this?

This isn't a question about how to get `\prime` to be a superscript, I know that. The questions is about the reasoning behind why it isn't like that *by default*.

Comment: Probably not what you're asking either, but `'` produces a superscript “prime”. Maybe `\prime` is just the command that holds the symbol, and it's only intended to use for defining other commands (such as `'`)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is actually one of the exercises in The TeXBook `:)` (exercise 16.5, p. 130):

> Why do you think TeX treats `\prime` as
>   a large symbol that appears only in
>   superscripts, instead of making it a
>   smaller symbol that has already been
>   shifted up into the superscript
>   position?

And the answer is:

> The second alternative doesn’t work
>   properly when there’s a subscript at
>   the same time as a prime. Furthermore,
>   some mathematicians use `\prime` also in
>   the subscript position; they write,
>   for example, `$F'(w,z)=\partial F(w,z)/\partial z$`
>   and `$F_\prime(w,z)=\partial F(w,z)/\partial w$`.

Comment: subscripted primes!? I've never seen that. Still, I guess the problem with it not working well if there's a subscript is legitimate...

Comment: Anyway, it seems the most natural choice, given that TeX has no "real" superscripts, just regular font (with proper optical size, if any) scaled down, so treating `\prime` the same way is natural in the sense that it fits with the rest of the system.

Comment: I always thought that the `\prime` macro existed so that one can write expressions such as `f^{\prime,n}`. After reading your answer I realized that `f'^n` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

There are situations where you need the big `\prime` instead of small `'`
e.g. `$J^{v\prime h}$` looks great, but `$J^{v ' h}$` wont serve as good as the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

If the default is subscript, that would appear to make the regular form inaccessible, essentially removing functionality.

edit: this appears to mesh with a statement on wikipedia which suggests the prime symbol is big so that it can be optionally subscripted.