# \prime gives "Undefined control sequence" in xelatex with unicode-math

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode-math

I cannot seem to be able to create a prime (') in any custom font. This, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math, polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin}]{timesi.ttf}
\begin{document}
  Hello, I want A-prime: 
  $$A^\prime.$$
\end{document}
```

gives `"Undefined control sequence [  $$A^\prime]"` error. I've tried `A'`, `A\prime`, `A^\prime`, none works. Without the \setmathfont command, xelatex works fine, outputting the expected A' in the standard CM font. I found this: [What is the right way to input prime with Unicode-math (LuaTeX backend)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30115) from 3 years ago, but they are concerned about the correct placement of prime, whereas for my example xelatex won't even recognise such command exists. I'd sure be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: That font is not a math font.

Comment: I subset it for Latin letters only. Shouldn't it leave the symbols alone?

Comment: You see this even with 'proper' math mode fonts: I suspect it's a `unicode-math` bug

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Say `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`, or `\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}` if you haven't installed it on your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there are appearing bugs in `unicode-math`.

Here's a workaround: load the prime from a math font *after* loading the fonts. By the way, it's necessary to call `\setmathfont` with the original font after any others to set the correct “fontdimens”.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math,polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Gentium}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin}]{Gentium Italic}
\setmathfont[range={"2032}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range={\int}]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
Hello, I want A-prime: \[ A^\prime \textrm{ or } x' \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used TeX Gyre Pagella Math because it looks better in my example, with Latin Modern Math you only need

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin}]{Gentium Italic}
\setmathfont[range={"2032}]{Latin Modern Math}
```

Comment: That does it for me, thank you! Should I try to report it, or is this behaviour by design for symbols missing in current font?