# scrartcl 14pt with unicode-math and XITS math: strange prime

Tags: xetex, koma-script, unicode-math

Please consider this minimal example. Compiled with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
Test $\exists a'$.%^\prime: same.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

As you can see the "prime" is too high (above the \exists symbol). The problem does not happen when using fontsize 12 pt or removing \setmathfont.

Any idea what’s wrong? What is the recommended way of changing the default font to 14 pt? I thought about using Scale (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141694/change-default-font-size-while-using-fontspec)) but I’m not sure scaling a big amount (one sixth) is recommended.

Comment: Tested both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but the prime comes out right.

Comment: I had the same question a couple years ago. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30115/5895 the answer there will not work anymore. But at the end of question I have updated the solution to work with most recent Unicode-math

Comment: @YanZhou: thanks. If my problem comes from too old version of my packages, as egreg suggests, then I’ll rather wait that the updates reach my distribution. I don’t understand what the patch suggested in the other answer does and I’m a bit reluctant to just work around the bug rather than properly solve it.

Comment: You won't solve this problem by updating package (probably ever). It is typeface specific issue. See the first answer in the question I referred to for an explanation

Comment: @YanZhou I suspect I can because the problem does not happen for egreg. By "updating package" I meant to include "update typeface". (I referred to the package distribution mechanism of the GNU/Linux distribution I use, not specifically to LaTeX distribution.) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can try. But I have both the latest TeXlive and the typeface and the issue still persist. And Linux distribution will be behind as always, and depending on your distribution, it maybe far behind

Comment: @egreg: are you sure? (See above comment.) I use XeTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian), Package: unicode-math 2014/06/30 v0.7f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

> ```
> *File List*
> scrartcl.cls    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script document class (article)
> scrkbase.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
>  scrbase.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
>   keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
> scrlfile.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
> tocbasic.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
>   size14.clo    1999/11/11 v1.4a NON-Standard LaTeX file (size option)
> typearea.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (type area)
> unicode-math.sty    2017/01/27 v0.8d Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
>  ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
> ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
>    expl3.sty    2017/04/01 L3 programming layer (loader) 
> expl3-code.tex    2017/04/01 L3 programming layer 
> l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
> ucharcat.sty    2015/11/19 v0.03 ucharcat for luaLaTeX (DPC)
>   xparse.sty    2017/04/01 L3 Experimental document command parser
> l3keys2e.sty    2017/04/01 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
> fontspec.sty    2017/03/31 v2.6a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
> fontspec-luatex.sty    2017/03/31 v2.6a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
>
>  fontenc.sty
>    tuenc.def    2017/02/22 v2.0g Standard LaTeX file
> fontspec.cfg
>   fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
>   ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
> filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
> filehook-scrlfile.sty    2011/01/03 v0.1 filehook patch for scrlfile package
> unicode-math-luatex.sty    
> lualatex-math.sty    2016/04/16 v1.6 Patches for mathematics typesetting with LuaLaTeX
> etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
>  ***********
> ```

I get

[image: lualatex example]

Same with XeLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX. So the problem seems to be solved using updated packages.

Comment: You must be right. I now realize that TexLive as packaged in my Debian stable distribution (Jessie) is very old. Checking my file list with \listfiles, many packages of mine are much older than yours. I suppose my problem will be solved when switching to the upcoming Debian release (Stretch).