# Typesetting \prime vs '

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to figure out how to best typeset primed values. It seems that, e.g.

`$f'$` and `$f\prime$` give off a slightly different result:

[image]

I like the right (`$a\prime$`) version better, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

**EDIT** after going over my preamble, I found the "culprit" - it was the package `unicode-math`, which I added to be able to use `\Colon`. After removing it, my primes rendered exactly like in Mico's answer.

Comment: Unicode-math changes the math font to Latin Modern Math.  You can select any other math font whose primes you like better, or even `\setmathfont[range=\prime]`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> It seems that, e.g. `$f'$` and `$f\prime$` give off a slightly different result

First off, the item on the left-hand side of the screenshot you posted does *not* appear to have been created by either `$f'$` and `$f\prime$` -- at least not by either TeX or LaTeX. See also the screenshot below and the associated LaTeX code.

The item on the right-hand side *could* have been created by either `$f'$` or `$f^{\prime}$`, since the two methods are entirely equivalent.

In math mode, `x'` and `x^{\prime}` are equivalent. The former is a lot easier to type, though. This becomes especially evident for higher-order derivatives: Speaking for myself, I'd much rather type `$f'''$` than `$f^{\prime\prime\prime}$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
$f' \quad f^{\prime} \quad f\prime$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bit of context: I'm converting Bartosz Milewski's blogpost series on category theory to a [PDF in LaTeX](https://github.com/hmemcpy/milewski-ctfp-pdf), which I based on the work (mainly, preamble.tex) from another book. Unfortunately, I'm very new to LaTeX, so I'm learning it as I go :))

Comment: Perhaps it's the combination of packages in `preamble.tex` which cause this? [Here's the one](https://github.com/hmemcpy/milewski-ctfp-pdf/blob/master/src/preamble.tex) I'm using now, but I'll try to make a small repro with minimal preamble.

Comment: And oh yeah, it certainly looks much better in your example. I'm going to try and experimenting with removing packages from my preamble.tex, until it looks ok :) I'll accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: @IgalTabachnik - That's a [rather complex and complicated preamble](https://github.com/hmemcpy/milewski-ctfp-pdf/blob/master/src/preamble.tex), by the way. I harbor some doubts that it has to be so complex...

Comment: You may be right :) I'm trimming it a bit as I go. It was originally a preamble used for a Texinfo/LaTeX version of SICP I found https://github.com/sarabander/sicp-pdf

Comment: @IgalTabachnik I would recommend starting with an empty preamble and building it up as you go.

Comment: I figured out what it was -- the package `unicode-math`, I used it to be able to use `\Colon`. I'm looking for workarounds. Will add this info to the original question.

Comment: @IgalTabachnik - Wow, in my view, the fact that the `unicode-math` package doesn't define (or possibly undefines) `\prime` is serious trouble. Happily, `$f'$` does work if `unicode-math` is loaded.

Comment: @Mico I've been reading about it a bit more, seems that I'm [not the only one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30115/what-is-the-right-way-to-input-prime-with-unicode-math-luatex-backend) who ran into these issues. In either case, I'll leave it be for now, and deal with it once the book is fully converted :) Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @IgalTabachnik - Great news: After you provided the comment that `unicode-math` was the likely source of the issue, some four hours ago, I contacted the maintainer of the `unicode-math` package, and he's already provided a bug fix and pushed it out to TeXLive! (Not sure when the fix will show up on MikTeX, in case that's what you're using.) If you update your TeX distribution to version 0.8h of unicode-math, the `\prime` directive should once again work. Isn't this a great community or what?! (Of course, I still think that writing `$y'$` is more convenient than `$y^{\prime}$`...)

Comment: @Mico that is incredible! Even a better resolution I could have hoped for! I'm using MacTeX, if that matters. Again, thanks so much, this is indeed a great community, and will go to the acknowledgments section :)

Comment: @IgalTabachnik - I'm also a MacTeX user. :-)