# How to center a table in the widetext envrionment of the template `revtex'?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, revtex

I'd like to center a table in the the widetext envrionment of the template `revtex`, however it didn't work even if I use the command `\centering`, it also keep the twocolumns state. How can I make the table centered?

What's more, I've asked the samilar question about centering a tcolorbox in that environment and the answer is just add a `[width=\textwidth]` after the command `\begin{tcolorbox}`, so I tried add the same command after the command `\begin{table}` or `\begin{tabular}`, however it returned me a lot of errors.
The following is my MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[reprint,bibnotes,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prb,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{A derivation to the article:\\Time-dependent transport in (non)interacting resonant-tunneling systems}

\maketitle
\begin{widetext}
    \centering
    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Rules for analytic continuation}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Contour} & Real Axis \\
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{$C=\int_CAB$} & $C^<=\int_t[A^rB^<+A^<B^a]$ \\
              & $C^r=\int_tA^rB^r$ \\
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{$D=\int_CABC$} & $D^<=\int_t[A^rB^rC^<+A^rB^<C^a+A^<B^aC^a]$ \\
              & $D^r=\int_tA^rB^rC^r$ \\
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{$C(\tau,\tau^\prime)=A(\tau,\tau^\prime)B(\tau,\tau^\prime)$} & $C^<(t,t^\prime)=A^<(t,t^\prime)B^<(t,t^\prime)$ \\
              & $\begin{aligned}
                C^r(t,t^\prime)=&A^<(t,t^\prime) B^r(t,t^\prime)+A^r(t,t^\prime)B^<(t,t^\prime)\\
                &+A^r(t,t^\prime)B^r(t,t^\prime)
              \end{aligned}$ \\
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{$D(\tau,\tau^\prime)=A(\tau,\tau^\prime)B(\tau^\prime,\tau)$} & $D^<(t,t^\prime)=A^<(t,t^\prime)B^>(t^\prime,t)$ \\
              & $D^r(t,t^\prime)=A^<(t,t^\prime)B^a(t^\prime,t)+A^r(t,t^\prime)B^<(t^\prime,t)$ \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%
  \end{widetext}
\end{document}
```

[image: The table can't be centered even if I'v used the command centering]

Comment: Just curious: Why do you write `^\prime` instead of `'`?

Comment: emm in my opinion, I think `\prime` is more professional than `'`.

Comment: As the old saying goes, you're entitled to your own opinions, but you're *not* entitled to your own facts. For some facts see, e.g., the postings [What is the advantage of using `$f^\prime$` instead of `$f'$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87134/5001), [Difference between `\prime` and `'` in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538395/5001) and [Typesetting `\prime` vs `'`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395415/5001). The outputs of `\prime` and `'` in math mode are guaranteed to be the same *by design*.

Comment: OK, thank you for your suggestions, I've treated my "obsessive-compulsive disorder" of using the command `^\prime` for 5 years... In addition, could you solve my question of "centering a table in revtex" which was referred above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the `revtex` document class lets users employ `\centering` in `widetext` environments in ways we might be used to doing in other LaTeX document classes. At any rate, it's not particularly difficult to make the table fit inside the width of a normal column. Oh, and I'd use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment to save myself from having to type lots and lots of `$` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass[reprint,bibnotes,amsmath,amssymb,
               aps,prb]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}
\title{A derivation to the article: Time-dependent transport \\
in (non)interacting resonant-tunneling systems}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Rules for analytic continuation}
$\begin{array}{@{} ll @{}}
\toprule
\text{Contour} & \text{Real Axis} \\
\midrule
C=\int_C AB
     & C^< = \int_t [A^rB^<+A^<B^a] \\ 
     \addlinespace
     & C^r = \int_t A^rB^r \\
\addlinespace[9pt]
D=\int_C ABC
     & D^< = \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
               \int_t[A^rB^rC^< +A^rB^<C^a \\
               \quad +A^<B^aC^a]
             \end{array} \\ 
     \addlinespace
     & D^r =\int_t A^rB^rC^r \\
\addlinespace[9pt]
C(\tau,\tau')=A(\tau,\tau')B(\tau,\tau')
     & C^<(t,t') = A^<(t,t')B^<(t,t') \\ 
     \addlinespace
     & C^r(t,t') =
             \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
               A^<(t,t') B^r(t,t')\\
               \quad +A^r(t,t')B^<(t,t')\\
               \quad +A^r(t,t')B^r(t,t')
             \end{array} \\
\addlinespace[9pt]
D(\tau,\tau') =A(\tau,\tau')B(\tau',\tau) 
     & D^<(t,t') = A^<(t,t')B^>(t',t) \\ 
     \addlinespace
     & D^r(t,t') = 
             \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
               A^<(t,t')B^a(t',t)\\
               \quad +A^r(t,t')B^<(t',t) 
             \end{array} \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
  
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I can’t imagine that the layout in two column is so beautiful